# How to extract cells with text and different number sizes

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am using VBA and I want to extract the following:

`TEST-1, TEST-11, TEST-111` or `TEST-1111` from a cell.

The regex that I've currently got is:

```
RE.Pattern = "(TEST-\d{3,4})"
```

This just extracts cells with either `TEST-111` or `TEST-1111`. (It does not extract `TEST-1` or `TEST-11`, which I also need) I have tried several different iterations or my regex with no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: This should be of some use to you: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use "(TEST-\d{1,4})" regexp.
This regex match all your exampless (see http://myregexp.com?regex=TEST-%5Cd%7B1,4%7D&text=TEST-1%20TEST-11%20TEST-111%20TEST-1111)